# No matching function for call to SocketIOClient::SocketIOClient()

Tags: c++, node.js, socket.io, arduino

I'm trying to maintain a communication between node JS server and Arduino using SocketIO, I tried to test this example (arduinoChat) https://github.com/quentinpigne/socket.io-arduino-client and I get this error:

```
  arduinochat.ino:6:16: error: no matching function for call to ‘SocketIOClient::SocketIOClient()’
    arduinochat.ino:6:16: note: candidates are:
    In file included from arduinochat.ino:4:0:
    /home/nourhene/sketchbook/libraries/SocketIOClient/SocketIOClient.h:52:3: note: SocketIOClient::SocketIOClient(Client&)
       SocketIOClient(Client& client);
       ^
    /home/nourhene/sketchbook/libraries/SocketIOClient/SocketIOClient.h:52:3: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
    /home/nourhene/sketchbook/libraries/SocketIOClient/SocketIOClient.h:50:7: note: SocketIOClient::SocketIOClient(const SocketIOClient&)
     class SocketIOClient {
           ^
    /home/nourhene/sketchbook/libraries/SocketIOClient/SocketIOClient.h:50:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
    arduinochat.ino: In function ‘void setup()’:
    arduinochat.ino:30:55: error: invalid conversion from ‘void (*)(EthernetClient, char*)’ to ‘void (*)(Client&, ArduinoJson::JsonArray&)’ [-fpermissive]
    In file included from arduinochat.ino:4:0:
    /home/nourhene/sketchbook/libraries/SocketIOClient/SocketIOClient.h:56:8: note: initializing argument 2 of ‘void SocketIOClient::setEventHandler(char*, void (*)(Client&, ArduinoJson::JsonArray&))’
       void setEventHandler(char* eventName, void (*handler)(Client& client, JsonArray& data));
            ^
```

arduinochat.ino : 6 : 16 =>

```cpp
SocketIOClient client;
```

SocketIOClient.h:52:3: =>

```cpp
class SocketIOClient {
    public:
        SocketIOClient(Client& client);
```

Comment: `SocketIOClient(Client& client)` is not the same as `SocketIOClient()`

Comment: @gre_gor so what should I add at this code  ! the error at line 6 https://github.com/quentinpigne/socket.io-arduino-client/blob/master/examples/arduino-chat/arduino-chat/arduino-chat.ino

Comment: Maybe use the example from the readme?

Comment: yup ! no more errors ! Now when I run this code https://github.com/quentinpigne/socket.io-arduino-client/blob/master/examples/arduino-chat/arduino-chat/arduino-chat.ino on my arduino it print socketIO not connected and when I try to print (client.connect(hostname , 3000)) that return 0 :(  ! the server listening at port 3000 and I changed the host name by my ip adress  ! any Idea ?